# Mysql connection from pymysql

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

I have created two classes class1 and class2 and getting pymysql connection in each classes....
I am updating a mysql database table in class1 and retrieving the same table in class2. But, after updating a row from class1, if I tried to retrieve from class2, the retrieved result is not containing the updated row, instead it is giving the old data...

Comment: Ok, I got the solution to the problem...

Comment: Please verify it, if i am wrong..

Comment: I have created the class Database shown below..

Answer (score 0):

I have created the class `Database` and connecting to the database. If I want to execute a query in class1 or class2, I will just call the function in `Database` and passing the SQL query to execute and will return the result to respective classes.

`database.py` file is shown below.

```
import pymysql

class Database:   
    def __init__(self): # WORKS
        self.db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="invexl")
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()

    def create(self, sql):
        try:
            self.cur.execute(sql)
            return self.db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.db.rollback()
            return str(e)

    def retrieve(self, sql):
        try:
            done = self.cur.execute(sql)
            result = self.cur.fetchall()
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.db.rollback()
            return str(e)


    def update(self, sql):
        try:
            self.cur.execute(sql)
            return self.db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.db.rollback()
            return str(e)


    def delete(self, sql):
        try:
            self.cur.execute(sql)
            return self.db.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            self.db.rollback()
            return str(e)
```